# Imagem corrompida usando UploadedFile do primefaces com FTPClient

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Olá pessoal estou com problema no componente do Primefaces "File Upload", ao tentar salvar o arquivo via "FtpClient" o arquivo fica corrompido.

Configuração do form

```
<h:form id="formNavegacao" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

A parte do FileUpload no arquivo web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
    <param-value>commons</param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <!--Tags rewrites para upload do primefaces-->
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Segue meu xhtml onde utilizo o componente.

```
                                <p:fileUpload id="navegacaoSuperiorMenuLogoTipo"
                                          styleClass="navegacaoSuperiorMenuLogoTipo waves-effect waves-light btn left-align"
                                          update="navegacaoComponente:formNavegacao:navegacao"
                                          auto="true" mode="advanced" skinSimple="true" 
                                          label="#{text['AdicionarLogotipo']}"
                                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"
                                          fileUploadListener="#{editorMB.salvaArquivoTmp}"/>
```

Método onde capturo a imagem

```
    public void salvaArquivoTmp(FileUploadEvent fileUploadEvent) {
    try {
        UploadedFile uploadedFile = fileUploadEvent.getFile();
        if (uploadedFile != null) {
            sessionMB.getConexaoFtp().enviarArquivoFtp("logotipo-tmp.png", uploadedFile.getInputstream());
            layout.getTopo().setCaminhoLogotipo(sessionMB.getEmpresa().getDominio() + "/" + "logotipo-tmp.png");
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        GerenciadorBugs.enviandoBug(TratamentoErro.setValoresException(exception));
    }
}
```

A classe onde insiro o arquivo via FtpClient

```
package br.com.redew.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class ConexaoFtp {

    private String host;
    private String usuario;
    private String senha;
    private String pastaInicial;
    private final FTPClient fTPClient;

    public ConexaoFtp() {
        fTPClient = new FTPClient();
    }

    private void conectandoFtp() throws IOException {
        fTPClient.connect(host);
        fTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        fTPClient.login(usuario, senha);
        fTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory(pastaInicial);
    }

    private void desconectandoFtp() throws IOException {
        fTPClient.logout();
        fTPClient.disconnect();
    }

    public void enviarArquivoFtp(String caminho, InputStream arquivo) {
        try {
            conectandoFtp();
            fTPClient.storeFile(caminho, arquivo);
            desconectandoFtp();
        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            GerenciadorBugs.enviandoBug(TratamentoErro.setValoresException(iOException));
        }
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getPastaInicial() {
        return pastaInicial;
    }

    public void setPastaInicial(String pastaInicial) {
        this.pastaInicial = pastaInicial;
    }
}
```

Ao subir um arquivo "html" via "FtpClient" funcionou agora quando tento subir uma imagem o arquivo fica corrompida.

Primefaces 6.1

Comment: Testou imagens de vários tamanhos e em todas o problema ocorre?

Comment: Sim apenas imagem fica corrompida vindo do componente File Upload, arquivo como tipo "txt" ou "html" eu testei e funcionou.

Comment: Acho que o problema não deve ser com o componente JSF, mas com o FTP. Faça um teste, no método conectandoFtp() adicione a instrução `fTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);`

Comment: Tentei aqui ainda continuar corrompida coloquei nesse link a imagem http://www.weder.sitepessoal.com/logotipo-tmp.png

Comment: Lá no diretório que você salva a imagem pelo FTP, chegou a verificar se a extensão do arquivo está correta. Por exemplo, se não está algo como _imagem.png.png_. Veja se o tamanho da imagem é o mesmo da original. Não consegui identificar nada de errado no código.

Comment: Então verifiquei o nome está correto, e os dois arquivo por incrível que pareça tem o mesmo tamanho 25 KB.

Comment: É... difícil. De repente tenta salvar esse arquivo em um diretório qualquer, sem usar o FTP, só para verificar se salva certinho ou não. Dai vai ter uma confirmação se o problema é com o FTP ou não.

Comment: Salvei o arquivo na minha maquina e funcionou, o problema mesmo é com FTP que triste kk.

Answer (score 0):

Testei hoje e funcionou acho que era problema de cache para não ter funcionado antes, está resolvido.

> fTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

Comment: Puxa... que coisa. Ainda bem que você resolveu testar novamente essa instrução.